# jbossws webservice endpoint

Tags: jbossws

I have developed a simple webservice implementation using top-down approach, created a war and deployed in jboss4.2.2GA, in windows environment.

I am able to see my webservice having registered end point, in http://localhost:8080/jbossws/services. But when i click on the endpoint hyperlink, I am not able to view the wsdl page.

Is it expected behaviour? Is there anyway, i can see the wsdl page on navigating through registered webservice endpoint hyperlink?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing a blank page when you click the link? You might need to view the page source to see the actual WSDL content. I think IE will display the WSDL by default, but Firefox and Chrome will not.